# Retriving OpenEvent Details using SubscriberKey

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to get the OpenEvent details for a specific SubscriberKey using the ExactTarget API. I have the SendID, BatchID and the SubscriberKey, the thing is that the filter of the SubscriberKey is not working. If I try to make the call with the filter for SendID I get the results(to many) but once I add the filter for the SubscriberKey the request returns nothing.

I try it on .NET and Java and I'm getting the same results.

For example I made a test using only the filter for SendID(142865) and I get these results

```
ObjectID: 3374303431

EventDate: 3/4/2014 2:03:49 PM

SendID: 142865

SubscriberKey: example1@example.es

BatchID: 4


ObjectID: 3374303432

EventDate: 3/4/2014 2:03:49 PM

SendID: 142865

SubscriberKey: example2@example.es

BatchID: 2



ObjectID: 3374303433

EventDate: 3/4/2014 2:03:49 PM

SendID: 142865

SubscriberKey: example3@example.es

BatchID: 1
```

If I try to make a call using the filter for SubscriberKey(example1@example.es) I get norhing

This is my java code:

```
RetrieveRequest retrieveRequest = RetrieveRequest.Factory.newInstance();
retrieveRequest.setObjectType("OpenEvent");
retrieveRequest.setPropertiesArray(new String[] { "ObjectID", "SendID", "SubscriberKey", "BatchID" });

SimpleFilterPart filter = SimpleFilterPart.Factory.newInstance(); 
filter.setProperty("SubscriberKey"); 
filter.setSimpleOperator(SimpleOperators.EQUALS); 
filter.setValueArray(new String[] { "example@example.com" }); 

retrieveRequest.setFilter(filter);
.
.
.
.
```

Please any help would be appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you filter by EmailAddress instead of SubscriberKey?

Comment: Francisco - welcome to SFSE - I took the liberty of making your post more readable by formatting the code using the {} command, please use that in the future

Comment: Sorry, this is not really an answer. I want to comment but it doesn't let me because of my points. I created an account and by some reason it was not linked with my question. crop1645 - Thanks for formatting the code part. I'll use it next time :) Timothy - I try using the EmailAddress instead of the SubscriberKey but I'm getting the same result

Comment: I'm looking at the first set of results and I see example1@example.es, example2@example.es, and example3@example.es.  Are you sure example@example.es is a subscriber in your data?

Comment: Timothy - Yes, the subscriber is in the data. The thing is if I filter for SendID I get a bunch of results. Then if I pick one of the results and use the SubscriberKey that is on that record to filter, the results are empty. Really don't know why the SubscriberKey filter is not working on the OpenEvent object.