# Tracking information from ExactTarget using FuelSDK for Java

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, java

I'm trying to get Tracking information from ExactTarget using FueldSDK for Java, but it doesn't seem to include the class `ETOpenEvent` as in other languages.

For [example](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/tracking/open-tracking.html#csharpget), with C# you can do this:

```
Using FuelSDK;
ET_Client myclient = new ET_Client();
ET_OpenEvent openevent = new ET_OpenEvent();
openevent.AuthStub = myclient;
GetReturn results = openevent.Get();
Console.WriteLine("Get Status: " + results.Status.ToString());
```

How do I do this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this url: [Retriving OpenEvent Details using SubscriberKey](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45944/retriving-openevent-details-using-subscriberkey)
with this example:

```
RetrieveRequest retrieveRequest = RetrieveRequest.Factory.newInstance();
retrieveRequest.setObjectType("OpenEvent");
retrieveRequest.setPropertiesArray(new String[] { "ObjectID", "SendID", "SubscriberKey", "BatchID" });

SimpleFilterPart filter = SimpleFilterPart.Factory.newInstance(); 
filter.setProperty("SubscriberKey"); 
filter.setSimpleOperator(SimpleOperators.EQUALS); 
filter.setValueArray(new String[] { "example@example.com" }); 

retrieveRequest.setFilter(filter);
```